# Laravel - Schema create chaining methods

Tags: laravel, database, schema

i have an app that allows user to create schema and basically what i need it to do is i need to check if user has checked certain attributes for a table column and if yes, add those attributes in schema create method. Here is the code i have written so far but the problem with this code is it doesn't create multiple rows. It creates the first row only.

```
Capsule::schema()->create($title, function ($table) use ($rows) { 
    $table->increments('id');

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        switch ($row["row-type"])
        {
            case 1:
                    $table->float($row["row-name"]);
                return;
            case 2:
                    $table->string($row["row-name"], $row["row-max-val"]);
                return;
        }
    
        if($row["row-def"] != "")
        {
            $table->default($row["row-def"]);
        }
    
        if($row["row-required"] == 0)
        {
            $table->nullable();
        }
    
        if($row["row-unique"] == 1)
        {
            $table->unique();
        }
    }
});
```

The switch statement check if the row is going to be integer or varchar, and the rest checks if the row is going to be required and if the user wants it to be required, $row["row-required"] will be 1 so i put it in the if statement to check if the user doesnt want it to be required, it will be set to 0 which tells the schema to add the nullable attribute to the column. With this code i managed to get the first row to work but the rows after that doesn't work. The table only has 2 rows, first one is the id which is in every table and the other row is the first row in the request.

I put the rows data from the request in foreach and added the rows according to the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you have some problems in your code.

First is The `return` inside the `switch` exits the anonymous function. I think what you want there is to put `break` instead of return.

Second is after the `switch` you want to check if the column is required or unique etc. What you did is you're using `$table` which it doesn't know what column should it be applied required or unique.

Anyway I think the below code hopefully solves your problem:

```
Capsule::schema()->create($title, function ($table) use ($rows) { 
    $table->increments('id');

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $column = null;
        switch ($row["row-type"])
        {
            case 1:
                    $column = $table->float($row["row-name"]);
                break;
            case 2:
                    $column = string($row["row-name"], $row["row-max-val"]);
                break;
        }

        if ($column === null)
        {
            continue;
        }
    
        if($row["row-def"] != "")
        {
            $column->default($row["row-def"]);
        }
    
        if($row["row-required"] == 0)
        {
            $column->nullable();
        }
    
        if($row["row-unique"] == 1)
        {
            $column->unique();
        }
    }
});
```